# Every Time I run a program in VSCode it gives me some sort of file location, how can I choose not to display this?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I run this in VsCode

```
package SourceCode;

/**
 * Hello
 */
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and my terminal and debug console both give me this as outputs for some reason, how do I get rid of this?

`"natesullivan@1x-nat-vl931-172-30-187-209 Compsci 187 %  cd "/Users/natesullivan/Desktop/Compsci 187" ; /usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:54943 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "/Users/natesullivan/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/ea87c260d6d4bad3c87c2b4a7cd1a37e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Compsci 187_bbd1ae4e/bin" SourceCode.Hello "`

Comment: Hello can u please fix your post, and state what you mean

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make input to your program, you can set the setting `java.debug.settings.console` to `internalConsole`.